# how to query for data that combines pricebook data + product data

Tags: soql, query

H everyone,

I am querying for some SF data for my frontend web app (a online restaurant) and have the below query

```
`SELECT Name, UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id = '01s5I000001FeddQAC' AND IsActive = true`;
```

this fetches everything i want except the product family which is in the products. I can fetch the this with

```
SELECT Name, Family FROM Product2
```

Is there anyway I can fetch combine these 2 queries and bring the Name, UnitPrice and Family?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Name, UnitPrice, Product2.Family,Product2.Name FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id = '01s5I000001FeddQAC' AND IsActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! This worked like a charm :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @Kisho If this solved your problem, you may at your option click the green check mark to accept the answer. This gives you both a bit of reputation.